# Auto Synch Google Calendar to Salesforce

Tags: integration

One of my project has a requirement to automatically create Salesforce Calendar entry once the Google event is created. I tried connection to Google API using Javascript, but that is on click of button. Is there a way to autmatically do the same?

Comment: One of the ideas may be creating scheduled job that runs once per some time, go check latest created events in google and add them in SF if needed

Comment: @kurunve But then how do I schedule Javascript code?

Comment: No javascript code, but apex. It is not possible to schedule JS code in SF without 3rd party service, but even in that case apex is involved

Comment: How do I synch Google calendar events using APEX. The rest endpoint do not work. Please let me know if there is any other way to connect via Apex. Thanks

Comment: @kurunve: Are there any other ways to integrate with Google Calendar

Comment: What do you mean by "rest endpoint do not work"? This can help you --
 there are even packages that helps to do that http://bit.ly/2pm6lXi